# How can I fetch data from a specific subcollection with React, typescript and firebase v9

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the react app I have a page where users can post information. I want other users to be able to comment to those posts. Currently the comments are updated to a specific subcollection by the id of the collection  in firebase, but I am not able to fetch those comments.

I get an error in the useEffect that I use to fetch the data. I've tried to define info by placing a "let info : any" at the top of the useEffect, but that didn't work.

My code looks like this:

```
export const Info = () => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
  const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
  const { user } = useAuthContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    const ref = query(collection(db, "Info"), orderBy("createdAt", "desc"));

    const unsub = onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
      let results: any = [];
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      setInfo(results);
    });
    return () => unsub();
  }, []);
  
  
  // I get an error with info.id in the useEffect

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const ref = query(
      collection(db, "Info", info.id, "comments"),
      orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
    );

    const unsub = onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
      let results: any = [];
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      setComments(results);
    });
    return () => unsub();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      {info.map((info: any) => (
        <Paper>
          <Grid
            container
            key={info.id}
            id={info.id}
            marginTop={2}
            marginBottom={2}
            alignItems="center"
          >
            <Grid item xs={4} justifyContent="start">
              <Typography variant="h6">{info.writer}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Paper style={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#652d90" }}>
              <Grid item md={12} xs={12}>
                <Typography
                  variant="h6"
                  className="goal"
                  style={{ color: "white" }}
                >
                  {info.title}
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item md={12} xs={12}>
                <Typography
                  variant="subtitle1"
                  className="goal"
                  style={{ color: "white" }}
                >
                  {info.content}
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Paper>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={1}>
                <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            {/*Comments*/}

            {comments.map((comment: any) => (
              <Grid container key={comment.id}>
                <Grid item xs={8}>
                  <Typography variant="h6">{comment.comment}</Typography>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            ))}

            <Grid container marginTop={1}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <form
                  onSubmit={(e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    const ref = collection(db, "Info", info.id, "comments");

                    addDoc(ref, {
                      comment: comment,
                      username: user.displayName,
                      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
                    });
                    setComment("");
                  }}
                >
                  <Grid container alignItems="center">
                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                      <ChatOutlinedIcon />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={7}>
                      <TextField
                        label="Add a comment..."
                        color="primary"
                        variant="standard"
                        fullWidth
                        value={comment}
                        onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                      ></TextField>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={1}>
                      <Button type="submit">Post</Button>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </form>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

The error that I get is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

This is the structure from firestore:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your Firestore structure and also the error that you are getting?

Comment: I have edited the my question